# Handle code after task are done

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, async-await

I'm trying to show a waiting symbol while while a ASYNC task are doing.

I'm really new to this, so if there are better ways to implement this code, please enlighten me :)

But, everything works except the hiding of the pictureBox1 after the code are done and there are now result found. In other words, when there are a result, the pictureBox1 are hidden

Here are the method that runs every time a outlook item are opened

```
private void FormRegion1_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {   
            if (this.OutlookItem is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)this.OutlookItem;
                getContactByEmail(item);                    
            }
    }
```

This is the method that I implement the wait stuff

```
public async Task getContactByEmail(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.....");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("tools/getContactByEmail?email=" + item.SenderEmailAddress + "&key=1232");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                SimpleContact contact = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SimpleContact>();

                lblName.Text = contact.Name;
                lblMobile.Text = contact.Phone;
            }

            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any exception? because if exception is thrown `pictureBox1.Visible = false;` won't execute

Comment: Great.. the problem was actually that the response.IsSuccessCode was true even though there was no result. then the lbl.text = contact.Name would try to set a null value. this was causing an exception. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome, You can delete the question or post answer yourself, you can accept it a day or 2 later :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting the code that fixes this so the exception are not raised

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    SimpleContact contact = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SimpleContact>();

    if (contact != null)
    {
      lblName.Text = contact.Name;
      lblMobile.Text = contact.Phone;
    }

   pictureBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` method names are always CamelCase and asynchronous methods are always suffixed **Async**. Just conventions.

You might want to extract the non UI code to another asynchronous method to avoid going back and forth to the UI thread:

```
private async void FormRegion1_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
        if (this.OutlookItem is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)this.OutlookItem;

            pictureBox1.Visible = true;

            var contact = GetContactByEmailAsync(item);

            if (contact != null)
            {
                lblName.Text = contact.Name;
                lblMobile.Text = contact.Phone;
            }

            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
}

public async Task<SimpleContact> GetContactByEmailAsync(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.....");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
            "tools/getContactByEmail?email=" + item.SenderEmailAddress + "&key=1232")
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SimpleContact>();
            : null;
    }
}
```

**Note: Don't forget proper exception handling!!!**